# How to have discrete colors in matplotlib colorbar instead of a gradient?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is the code + visual of my current subplots/colorbar (only the colorbar info matters for this question):

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(20,14))

embeddings=[px_embedding, px_embedding_labels, lv_embedding, lv_embedding_labels]
titles=['pixels', 'pixels with labels', 'lvs', 'lvs with labels']

index=0
for ax in axes.flat:
    im=ax.scatter(*embeddings[index].T, s=50, c=cluster_num, cmap='Spectral', alpha=1.0)
    ax.set_title(titles[index])
    index+=1
    
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
cbar = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar)

plt.show()
```

[image]

But, this is how I want the colorbar to look (ignore the plot):
[image]

I was able to achieve this colorbar with only one dataset/plot using the code below. cluster_num is a list of labels of all the points (integers ranging from 0 to 8), num_clusters=9 (the # of clusters/colors in the bar) and classes= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8].

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10, 7))
plt.scatter(*embedding.T, s=50, c=cluster_num, cmap='Spectral', alpha=1.0)
plt.setp(ax, xticks=[], yticks=[])
cbar = plt.colorbar(boundaries=np.arange(num_clusters+1)-0.5)
cbar.set_ticks(np.arange(num_clusters))
cbar.set_ticklabels(classes)
plt.title('Images');
```

But, I'm not sure how to do the same when I have four subplots instead of just one plot (colorbar is the same for each plot).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, did you try the same syntax? `fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar, boundaries=np.arange(num_clusters+1)-0.5)`?  Or is there something wrong in that case?  You might add `ax.scatter(....., vmin=-0.5, vmax=num_clusters-0.5)` to make sure that all plots use the same ranges.

Comment: Just got it! I didn't know there was a "ticks" parameter in there, so I did this instead. Thanks a lot! If you'd like me to accept your comment as an answer, just post it as an answer and I will : fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar, boundaries=np.arange(num_clusters+1)-0.5, ticks=list(np.arange(num_clusters)))

Comment: If you want to, you could add your solution as an answer and accept it.  (See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))

Comment: But preferable is to use a BoundaryNorm during the original scatter.